# Handshake failure when making t3s call

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, weblogic12c

I am setting up a new t3s channel in weblogic. When i try to invoke a call to this new channel, i get the below exception. I am using a self-signed certificate.

```
No available cipher suite for TLSv1.2
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                               ......(
main, called closeSocket()
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.activate(Handshaker.java:509)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.kickstartHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1474)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1346)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:750)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:138)
```

Logs after enabling ssl debug

```
%% No cached client session
update handshake state: client_hello[1]
upcoming handshake states: server_hello[2]
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1540414784 bytes = { 244, 150, 37, 122, 161, 146, 112, 42, 146, 1, 157, 89, 176, 65, 143, 62, 197, 121, 235, 202, 6, 196, 139, 184, 79, 38, 200, 208 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension extended_master_secret
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 111
0000: 01 00 00 6B 03 01 5C D1   DD 40 F4 96 25 7A A1 92  ...k..\..@..%z..
0010: 70 2A 92 01 9D 59 B0 41   8F 3E C5 79 EB CA 06 C4  p*...Y.A.>.y....
0020: 8B B8 4F 26 C8 D0 00 00   1E C0 0A C0 14 00 35 C0  ..O&..........5.
0030: 05 C0 0F 00 39 00 38 C0   09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0  ....9.8...../...
0040: 0E 00 33 00 32 00 FF 01   00 00 24 00 0A 00 16 00  ..3.2.....$.....
0050: 14 00 17 00 18 00 19 00   09 00 0A 00 0B 00 0C 00  ................
0060: 0D 00 0E 00 16 00 0B 00   02 01 00 00 17 00 00     ...............
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 111
[Raw write]: length = 116
0000: 16 03 01 00 6F 01 00 00   6B 03 01 5C D1 DD 40 F4  ....o...k..\..@.
0010: 96 25 7A A1 92 70 2A 92   01 9D 59 B0 41 8F 3E C5  .%z..p*...Y.A.>.
0020: 79 EB CA 06 C4 8B B8 4F   26 C8 D0 00 00 1E C0 0A  y......O&.......
0030: C0 14 00 35 C0 05 C0 0F   00 39 00 38 C0 09 C0 13  ...5.....9.8....
0040: 00 2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33   00 32 00 FF 01 00 00 24  ./.....3.2.....$
0050: 00 0A 00 16 00 14 00 17   00 18 00 19 00 09 00 0A  ................
0060: 00 0B 00 0C 00 0D 00 0E   00 16 00 0B 00 02 01 00  ................
0070: 00 17 00 00                                        ....
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
Handshake failed: TLSv1, error = Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to initialize JNDI context, tried 2 time or times totally, the interval of each time is 0ms. 
t3s://xyz:1234: Destination 192.168.16.104, 1234 unreachable.; nested exception is: 
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; No available router to destination.; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.ConnectException: No available router to destination. [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: t3s://xyz:1234: Destination 192.168.16.104, 1234 unreachable.; nested exception is: 
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; No available router to destination.; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.ConnectException: No available router to destination.]
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.throwRetryException(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:467)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:403)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:351)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:320)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:119)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
```

I have tried this:

Added the certificate generated from the keystore to java trust store.
telnet to the new channel created is working fine

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I have the exact same problem and don't know how to proceed. Thanks

Comment: Yes , i was able to resolve the issue.